# Using Kinect v2.0 (USB 3.0) with Raspberry Pi3 (USB 2.0)

Tags: raspberry-pi3, openni, kinect-v2

I just bought the USB Kinect adapter and realised it just works with USB 3.0. When connecting it to the USB 3.0 port of the PC everything works fine, but when I tried to connect to my Raspberry Pi3 it just won't work. I've already installed all the drivers (Openni,Sensorkinect) but when I execute the "Sample-NiSimpleRead" of OpenNI I get the following message:

```
One or more of the following nodes could not be enumerated:
Device: PrimeSense/SensorKinect/5.1.2.1: The device is not connected!
```

Besides, when I try `sudo lsusb -v|grep -i nui` I get:

```
iProduct                2 NuiSensor Adaptor
```

Still, there's no way to make it work. I've seen some projects in Youtube which use Raspberry3 and Kinect, so there should be one way to solve this. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Kinect v2 is solely USB3, while RPi is USB2 (as you stated). Maybe you've seen the videos of Kinect v1, which uses USB2?

Answer (score 0):

Kincect V2 needs USB-3, so if you need to plugin into a embedded device then Nvidia Jetson TK1/TX1/TX2 boards are the best bet. Here is a [link](http://www.jetsonhacks.com/2015/02/26/install-kinect-v2-using-libfreenect2-on-nvidia-jetson-tk1/) that shows a demo of Kinect-V2 with Jetson TK1. I have tried the same steps for TX2 and it works fine after the successful installation of "libfreenect2".